# Python Reportlab Area under multiple lines graph

Tags: python, graph, charts, reportlab, linegraph

So I have started a project for the web utilizing Reportlab. The website needs to generate PDFs that have embedded charts. So far I've been extremely happy with Reportlab's capabilities (i've done a bunch of pie and bar charts), however its documentation is kinda lacking.

I have looked all over the internet, and have been unable to find an example using reportlab of an Area under the graph chart. [image: See an example of what my client wants here]

Has anyone achieved the above result using reportlab? What are your suggestions for achieving the above chart?

Edit: Check out this chart from google chart API, it is basically what I would like to do:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart
    ?cht=lc
    &chd=e:....,cefhjkqwrlgYcfgc,QSSVXXdkfZUMRTUQ,HJJMOOUbVPKDHKLH,AAAA
    &chco=000000
    &chls=1,1,0|1,1,0|1,1,0|1,4,0
    &chs=200x125
    &chxt=x,y
    &chxl=0:|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|1:||50|100
    &chg=25,25
    &chm=b,76A4FB,0,1,0|b,224499,1,2,0|b,FF0000,2,3,0|b,80C65A,3,4,0
```

[image: google chart api link]

Comment: I don't see a specific example of how to do it, but you might try using MatPlotLib with ReportLab to generate this kind of chart.  I use MatPlotLib to generate lots of charts that I use in ReportLab-generated PDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built a collection of galleries under http://www.reportlab.com/chartgallery/ to serve as examples. I think what you need is the inFills property under the line, look at http://www.reportlab.com/chartsgallery/financial/AreaChart01/ for an example (also read the description there). You could browse the properties on the right to see their values.

You could also download a trial version of Diagra to build your charts and then convert them to use the open source version when ready to deploy to production.

Comment: this looks promising, I'm going to take a closer look. Thanks

Comment: The chartsgallery looks amazing, but could it be found in any way on the reportlab homepage? Or do you need to get hold of the link to it from some special place like this or the mailinglist? I can't seem to find it anyway...

Comment: @UlfR I wrote the charts before leaving ReportLab as a way to demonstrate various charts and to work as sexy examples. The plan was to publicise the page but I am not sure why it has not been made public yet. You could probably get an answer if you ask on the ReportLab mailing list.